# Why is this coroutines demo crashing?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

fun main() {
    coroutines()
    while (true) {
    }
}

fun coroutines() {
    val jobs = 1..100000
    jobs.forEach {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            val request = getRequest()
            val client = getClient()
            call(request, client)
        }
    }
}
```

I am running this on 16GB RAM, High Sierra.

I want to understand what's wrong I am doing here.
My intention is to create a program to understand how many coroutines we can create.

Before the program ends my machine gets restarted.

Answer (score 0):

> My intention is to create a program to understand how many coroutines we can create.

The program you wrote does not provide you with that answer. Rather, it puts a thin layer on top of the classic Java `ExecutorService` with up to 64 concurrent threads executing your `call()`. The reason why your computer reboots is entirely outside the code you posted in the question. It is probably related to what exactly your `call()` does.

If you want to observe the overhead the Kotlin coroutines introduce, you must write code that doesn't involve any heavyweight operations whose overhead dwarfs that of coroutines. Here's an example:

```
var maxConcurrentCalls = 0

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        coroutines()
    }
    println("You launched %,d concurrent coroutines".format(maxConcurrentCalls))
}

fun CoroutineScope.coroutines() {
    var concurrentCalls = 0
    val jobs = 1..1_000_000
    jobs.forEach {
        launch {
            concurrentCalls++
            maxConcurrentCalls = max(concurrentCalls, maxConcurrentCalls)
            delay(1000)
            concurrentCalls--
        }
    }
}
```

On my computer it ran for about 3 seconds and printed

```
You launched 1,000,000 concurrent coroutines
```

Note that all these coroutines executed on the main thread, which is why I had no need for thread-safe counters.